# exception exception while using schemaCrawler

Tags: java, oracle10g, schemacrawler

I got this exception while using schemaCrawler with Oracle Database 10g, does anyone know what did that mean?

```
Avertissement: JDBC driver does not support retrieving functions java.lang.AbstractMethodError: 
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDatabaseMetaData.getFunctions(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/sql/ResultSet; at 
schemacrawler.crawl.RoutineRetriever.retrieveFunctions(RoutineRetriever.java:159) at 
schemacrawler.crawl.SchemaCrawler.crawlRoutines(SchemaCrawler.java:178) at 
schemacrawler.crawl.SchemaCrawler.crawl(SchemaCrawler.java:457) at 
work.SchemaCrawlerUtility.getDatabase(SchemaCrawlerUtility.java:20)
```

Comment: What version of the JDBC driver are you using, and what version of the Oracle database?

Comment: For the JDBC driver i am using OJDBC14 to connect Oracle 10g express edition.

Comment: ojdbc14.jar is the name of the jar file - it is not the version of the Oracle driver. Please download the Oracle 11g driver, ojdbc6.jar from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html and try it. It will work with Oracle 10g Express Edition. Let me know how it works